# What is the fastest way to interpolate an Integral in Java?

Tags: java, math, interpolation, integral

I have a lot of datapoints and I want to compute the area under the curve for sliding windows. But It should be quite fast. I googled a bit and found a NewtonCotes implementation in Java, but I don´t know if there are faster methods.

Any Ideas?

Comment: We cannot answer your question without knowing your requirements as to the precision of the quadrature. Please consider reading some materials on [numerical analysis](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/wnnr/nr-alt.html) first.

Comment: It doesn´t need to be super precise, abs(E(f)) < 1 is ok. I already considered the trapezoid rule, but maybe there are methods I havent heard of which are faster. And the next thing is that  I don´t know which implementation is fast.

Comment: Define "fast".  What's your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the function you're trying to integrate.  Gauss quadrature can be very efficient indeed if applied to the right function.  5th order adaptive Runga-Kutta can do very well, too.

An adaptive method that automatically increases refinement to meet a given accuracy requirement is quite doable.

The fastest code to write is a library:

http://commons.apache.org/math/

I'd recommend a book like [Numerical Recipes](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=numerical%20recipes) or another by [Forman Acton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883854503).